# ViewModel not recognized after publish on Azure One or more compilation references are missing. Ensure that your project is referencing

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I've been readding about this error.

One or more compilation references are missing. Ensure that your project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' and the 'PreserveCompilationContext' property is not set to false.

This error means that some dependency is not being recognized.

My problem is that the missed class actually is a ViewModel on the project and not in an assembly reference

[image: The PostViewModel exist into the Models folder for the project]

When I build and run it into my development environment it works and no errors. 
The problem cames when I publish into my production environment on windows Azure App service,  when I try to reach the view that uses this model I get the error

Answer (score 0):

If you have renamed a model class in the Asp.Net Core MVC Project, then the entries are **only changed in the code files**.

The **view files .cshtml are not customized**.

You then have to rename the connected data model in the header of the view file.

Example:

```
@model Notes_Index_View_DataModel
```

To

```
@model Projects_Index_View_DataModel
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/aspnet/MvcPrecompilation) and this [blog](https://readdy.net/Notes/Details/501).